# Multiple conditions in in Sharepoint calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula

I am a bit new to SharePoint lists. I am trying to create a calculated column with multiple conditions as below.

So the priority needs to be automatically calculated based on other 2 columns Impact and Urgency. The numeric value below is the priority:

```
                   Urgency
Impact   High   Medium   Low
High      1       2       3 
Medium    2       3       4
Low       3       4       5
```

How to put a formula to automatically calculate Priority?

I tried with:

```
=IF(AND([Impact]="High",[Urgency]="High"),"1",IF(AND([Impact]="High",[Urgency]="Medium"),"2",IF(AND([Impact]="High",[Urgency]="Low"),"3",IF(AND([Impact]="Medium",[Urgency]="High"),"2",IF(AND([Impact]="Medium",[Urgency]="Medium"),"3",IF(AND([Impact]="Medium",[Urgency]="Low"),"4",IF(AND([Impact]="Low",[Urgency]="High"),"3",IF(AND([Impact]="Low",[Urgency]="Medium"),"4",IF(AND([Impact]="Low",[Urgency]="Low"),"5","")))))))))
```

The above is giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=IF([Impact]="High", IF([Urgency]="High", "1", IF([Urgency]="Medium", "2", IF([Urgency]="Low", "3", ""))), IF([Impact]="Medium", IF([Urgency]="High", "2", IF([Urgency]="Medium", "3", IF([Urgency]="Low", "4", ""))), IF([Impact]="Low", IF([Urgency]="High", "3", IF([Urgency]="Medium", "4", IF([Urgency]="Low", "5", ""))), "")))
```

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Return your calculated field as **Single line of text**.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: Thank you Ganesh Sanap! It works!

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.